# PDF просмотр на сайте и примонтированная сетевая папка в fstab

Tags: php, linux, debian, pdf, fstab

Суть проблемы:

Если файлы расположить в сетевой папке и примонтировать в локальную директорию Web-приложения, то pdf и фалы изображений отображаются некорректно. Например:

При открытии pdf, что-то с кодировкой, как-будто какого-то шрифта нет(ɨɦɧɚɫɬɨɹɳ). При открытии картинки, она как-будто недозагружена, с артефактами. Если я поменяю константу на обычную директорию, то все нормально.

Файлы открываю через тег `<a></a>`

Сайт крутится на debian+apache+php7.2 системе в локальной сети.

Что-бы не хранить фалы на сервере с приложением, хочу вынести их в сеть.

В корне сайта создал директорию mnt. 
На NAS создал шару, выдал конкретному пользователю полные права на нее

Далее, монтирую сетевую папку в mnt, вот так (в .smbcred прописал креды на шару):

```
//192.168.1.111/sites /var/www/site.ru/mnt cifs credentials=/root/.smbcred,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

права на mnt после монтирования

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 root    root       0 дек 31 22:23 mnt
```

Почему такое странное поведение? Ведь сами файлы целые, если их скачать и посмотреть любым другим способом (winScp например), все без проблем открывается. Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: Чуть позже попробую воспроизвести подобную ситуацию, но мне кажется, что проблема тут iocharset=utf8, если появляются артефакты

Comment: На картинках сразу воспроизвестись должно, pdf файлы не все показывают проблему

Comment: @Denis640Kb параметры чарсета влияют только на оглавление папок, т.е. на названия файлов, но ни как не на их содержимое.

Comment: @AndrewMedvedev Я так понимаю сами файлы раздает именно апач, а не приложение ?

Comment: @Mike Файл как есть загружаются через форму и складывается в нужную директорию и в ссылке передается путь к нему.

Comment: Вопрос в том, кто отдает файл клиенту, когда он жмет на ссылку. Я так подозреваю, что сам апач. А значит проблема в апаче. Попробуйте выключить использование mmap, установив опцию `EnableMMAP Off` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#enablemmap). По крайней мере нарыл сейчас информацию (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=900821), что существует баг в ядре linux ведущий к неправильному чтению файлов, расшаренных через cifs с использованием функции mmap, а апач ее как раз использует по умолчанию.

Comment: @Mike помогло, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема вызвана багом в ядре linux, приводящим к некорректному отображению файла, с примонтированной по cifs/nfs папки, на память функцией mmap(). Apache, который отдает файл клиенту, использует данную функцию для ускорения доступа к файлам. На сколько мне известно на данный момент нет лечения проблемы ядра. Для борьбы с проблемой необходимо запретить Apache использовать функцию mmap при работе с файлами. Для этого надо воспользоваться опцией [`EnableMMAP Off`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#enablemmap) конфигурационного файла. В связи с тем, что обращение к файлам без mmap несколько медленней, рекомендуется включать опцию только для примонтированной по сети папки.